# How can I only show a screenshot of the first page of a pdf in a React page?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, pdf

I'm trying to set up a dashboard that allows users to see a small preview of the first page of a pdf that they select with no other functionality available to them.

I tried simply embedding the pdf but that will allow users to scroll, zoom in and out, etc. I don't want the user to have this ability, they should only be able to see a screenshot of page 1.

This is what the file currently looks like:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { default as Grid } from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import { default as Paper } from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { default as Typography } from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { default as React } from 'react';
import Datatable from './components/datatable';
import { obj } from './components/theme';

// Used makeStyles to stylize the paper elements in the page

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  margin: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
  },
  paper2: {
    padding: theme.spacing(3, 2),
  },
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

export const OrdersList: React.FC = () => {

  const classes = useStyles(obj.theme);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={9}>
          <br />
          <Datatable />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={3} >
        <br />
          <Paper className={classes.paper2}>
            <Typography variant="h4" component="h3" gutterBottom>Lorem Ipsum</Typography>
            <embed src="pdf_source" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf"/>
          </Paper>
        <br />
        <br />
        <Paper className={classes.paper2}>
            <Typography variant="h4" component="h3" gutterBottom>Lorem Ipsum</Typography>
            <Typography variant="body1" component="h3" gutterBottom>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit</Typography>
          </Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read the pdf with JS to achieve that. I would recommend using pdf.js (https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) and the getPage method. after that, you can set it wherever you like. You can find it here: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/